# How can I translate a regex within vim to work with sed?

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I have a string that exists within a text file that I am trying to modify with regex.

```
"configuration_file_for_wks_33-40"
```

and I want to modify it so that it looks like this

```
"configuration_file_for_wks_33-40_6ks"
```

Within vim I can accomplish this with the following regex command

```
%s/33-\(\d\d\)/33-\1_6ks/
```

But if I try to pass that regex command to sed such as

```
sed 's/33-\(\d\d\)/33-\1_6ks/' input_file.json
```

The string is not changed, even if I include the -e parameter.

I have also tried to do this using ex as

```
echo '%s/33-\(\d\d\)/33-\1_6ks/' | ex input_file.json
```

If I use

```
sed  's/wks_33-\(\d\d\)*/wks_33-\1_6ks/' input_file.json
```

then I get

```
configuration_file_for_wks_33-_6ks40
```

For that, I've tried various different escaping patterns without any luck.

Can someone help me understand why this changes are not working?

Comment: Sed doesn't support `\d`. You have to use `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vim has a different syntax for regular expressions (which is even configurable). Unfortunately, sed doesn't understand `\d` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230/304256). With `-E`, you can match digits with `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`:

```
$ sed -E 's/33-[0-9][0-9]/&_6ks/'
configuration_file_for_wks_33-40_6ks
```

Note that you can use `&` in the replacement for adding the entire matched string.

So why is this:

```
$ sed  's/wks_33-\(\d\d\)*/wks_33-\1_6ks/' input_file.json
configuration_file_for_wks_33-_6ks40
```

Here, `(\d\d)*` is simply matched 0 times, so you replace `wks_33-` by `wks_33-_6ks` (`\1` is a zero-length string) and `40` remains where it was before.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I translate a regex within vim to work with sed?

Since you write "*a* regex", I think you refer to any regex.

Translating a Vim regex to a Sed regex is not always possible, because a Vim regex can have lookarounds, whereas a Sed regex has no such things.

Answer (score 2):

Translation from one language to another is best done with some reference material on hand:

- [`sed` BRE syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-syntax.html#BRE-syntax)
- [`sed` ERE syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/ERE-syntax.html#ERE-syntax)
- [`sed` classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions)
- [`sed` RE extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/regexp-extensions.html#regexp-extensions)

The superficial reading of which shows that `sed` doesn't support `\d`.

Possible alternatives to `\d\d`:

```
[[:digit:]]\{2\}
[0-9]\{2\}
```